# How do I dynamically set HTML5 data- attributes using react?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to render an HTML5 attribute of a `<select>` input so that I can use jquery image picker with react. My code is:

```
var Book = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <option data-img-src="{this.props.imageUrl}" value="1">{this.props.title}</option>
```

The issue is that even though `{this.props.imageUrl}` is getting properly passed as a `prop`, it isn't rendering in the HTML - it just renders as `{this.props.imageUrl}`. How can I make the variable pass through properly into the HTML?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You should not wrap JavaScript expressions in quotes.

```
<option data-img-src={this.props.imageUrl} value="1">{this.props.title}</option>
```

Take a look at [the JavaScript Expressions docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions) for more info.

Comment: I have one doubt from your answer, for this case how you can get that data-img-src value in any js events.If we need a value we can get by e.target.value but if i need imageUrl how i will get that???

Comment: @praveenkumar You can access them via `e.target.dataset`. See the [documentation for dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), the [documentation for data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), and [this CodePen example](https://codepen.io/BinaryMuse/pen/jaQVQM).

Answer (score 44):

Note - if you want to pass a data attribute to a React Component, you need to handle them a little differently than other props.

**2 options**

Don't use camel case

```
<Option data-img-src='value' ... />
```

And then in the component, because of the dashes, you need to refer to the prop in quotes.

```
// @flow
class Option extends React.Component {

  props: {
    'data-img-src': string
  }
```

And when you refer to it later, you don't use the dot syntax

```
  render () {
    return (
      <option data-img-src={this.props['data-img-src']} >...</option>
    )
  }
}
```

**Or use camel case**

```
<Option dataImgSrc='value' ... />
```

And then in the component, you need to convert.

```
// @flow
class Option extends React.Component {

  props: {
    dataImgSrc: string
  }
```

And when you refer to it later, you use the dot syntax

```
  render () {
    return (
      <option data-img-src={this.props.dataImgSrc} >...</option>
    )
  }
}
```

Mainly just realize `data-` attributes and `aria-` attributes are treated specially.  You are allowed to use hyphens in the attribute name in those two cases.

Comment: I just tried using an adhoc custom prop `caption-xl: boolean` and it just worked `<Typography caption-xl />`.