# Does React.js support HTML5 datalist?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-datalist

I'm trying to implement HTML5 datalist element in a easiest possible way.

Something like this:

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

This does not work however. What would be my next step without having to install (npm) additional stuff.

Basically, I'm using the plain **input** react element and want to embed the datalist.

Here is my react code:

```
    <input className={"custom_input inline "+this.isValidInteger(this.props.price.price_first,0,2000000)} 
    style={{marginRight:'5px'}} 
    value={this.props.price.price_first || ''} type="text"
    onChange={(e)=>this.props.dispatch({type:"price", payload:e.target.value})} 
    placeholder=" Unesite..." 
    maxLength="10"/>
```

So I would like a dropdown on top of that.

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285856/how-do-i-dynamically-set-html5-data-attributes-using-react

Comment: Supported `Dom` elements by `reactjs` - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm currently using the **html5 datalist** in react without issues.

Here goes the implementation:

```
<input type="text" list="data" onChange={this._onChange} />

  <datalist id="data">
    {this.state.data.map((item, key) =>
      <option key={key} value={item.displayValue} />
    )}
  </datalist>
```

Comment: How do I get the event when an option is selected from the dropdown either through keyboard or through click?

Comment: The datalist itself has no specific events to handle this. But what you can use is the oninput-event of the input element.
Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022728/perform-action-when-clicking-html5-datalist-option/32205204#32205204

Answer (score 13):

Datalists work fine in React, but you must close each option tag (with a backslash at the end).

```
<option value="something" />
```

Answer (score 4):

It takes a little change to make MDN datalist example works in React.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

```
<label>
    Choose a browser from this list:
    <input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" />  
</label>   
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Chrome" />
    <option value="Firefox" />
    <option value="Internet Explorer" />
    <option value="Opera" />
    <option value="Safari" />
    <option value="Microsoft Edge" />   
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with me using `useRef` hook; using the `useState` kinda have slow issue.

```html
<input type="text" ref={item_name_ref} onClick={(e)=>{item_name_ref.current.value=""}}  defaultValue = {props.selectedRecord.item_name} list="item_name_list"/>
<datalist id="item_name_list">
    {  
        productsName.map((item,index)=>{
          return  <option key={uuid()} value={item.item_name} />;
        })
    }
</datalist>
```

then I can grab the result in

```js
const handleClick=()=>{ alert(item_name.current.value)}
```

Answer (score -1):

Properly closing the option tag won't throw any error.

```
<input list="browsers">

// Not working code
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
</datalist>

//Working Code
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer" />
  <option value="Firefox" />
</datalist>
```