# React - input range with default step as an array of values

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

While working on a React Component, I'm trying to set a specific range of values to determine the `step` on a type range input.

I'm able to reproduce the desired behavior with vanilla HTML and JS i.e.

HTML

```
<!-- custom step range -->
<div class="step">
  <input id="input" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="4" step="1" list="tick-list">
  <datalist id="tick-list">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</datalist>
  <span id="output"></span>

</div>
```

JS

```
var values = [10,25,50, 75, 100];

var input = document.getElementById('input'),
   output = document.getElementById('output');
input.oninput = function(){
    output.innerHTML = values[this.value];
};
input.oninput();
```

see codepen [here](https://codepen.io/tonkihonks/pen/qBWqMNZ)

However, not able to achieve the same results when trying to wire this same functionality to React.

i.e.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      values : [10, 25, 50, 75, 100]
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = () => {
    const input = document.querySelector('input'),
    const output = document.getElementById('output');
    output = this.state.values;
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          oninput={this.handleInputChange()}
          type="range"
          min="0"
          value="0"
          max="4"
          step="1"
          list="tick-list" />
        <datalist id="tick-list">
          <option value="0" />
          <option value="1" />
          <option value="2" />
          <option value="3" />
          <option value="4" />
        </datalist>
        <span id="output">{this.state.values}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The above doesn't let me move the slide nor outputs the steps one at time.

**How could I wire this properly using React JS?**
Ps: Feel free to provide an example as a functional component rather than a class.

Comment: Try this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167565/does-react-js-support-html5-datalist

Comment: Perhaps using onChange instead of onInput

Comment: I tried onChange no dice. I'm wondering how to refactor from the working vanilla JS ex I posted to React.

Comment: Set the output to a state and output using the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can make use of [`state` in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to store the current index of your stepped input component, rather than finding the output DOM node and changing it's inner HTML.

Which would makes your `handleInputChange` function:

```
handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ currentStep: e.currentTarget.value });
  };
```

React operates on it's own virtual DOM, it changes the names of the HTML attributes on the DOM nodes to a React equivalent -> https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html.
Which means you'll need to change `oninput` to `onInput` in your component.

Here is one possible working version of your React component:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  values = [10, 25, 50, 75, 100];

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentStepIndex: 0
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ currentStepIndex: e.currentTarget.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onInput={this.handleInputChange}
          type="range"
          min="0"
          value={this.state.currentStepIndex}
          max="4"
          step="1"
          list="tick-list"
        />
        <datalist id="tick-list">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </datalist>
        <span id="output">{this.values[this.state.currentStepIndex]}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-cookies-vc9u8?fontsize=14)

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation and working example. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example for your react range:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      rangeValues: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
      currentRangeValue: 0
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ currentRangeValue: e.target.value });
  };


  render() {
    const { rangeValues, currentRangeValue } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          type={"range"}
          min={0}
          defaultValue={0}
          max={4}
          step={1}
          list={"tick-list"} />
        <datalist id="tick-list">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </datalist>
        <span id="output">{rangeValues[currentRangeValue]}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Check it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-water-z6fjv?fontsize=14

Comment: thank you so much for the working solution and codebox example. This is exactly what I was seeking after. I accepted Pitt answer since he posted a bit before.