# Ternary operator fails when used to set value of datalist option in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, conditional-operator

My code is written with React and I am trying to conditionally swap what gets assigned to value in each  element. swap is being passed in as a prop and I thought it would work to act as the trigger but I get no change when I use swap=true vs swap=null.

```html
function DataList({label, onSelect, options, swap}) {

    return (
        <DataListContainer>
            <CustomInput placeholder={label} list="items" name="item" id="item" required onChange={onSelect}></CustomInput>
            <datalist id='items' >
                {options? options.map(option => <option key={option.number} value={swap ? option.title : option.number}>{swap ? option.number : option.title}</option>) : null}
            </datalist>
        </DataListContainer>
    );
}
```

Here is the code that's actually rendering my component.

```html
<DataList 
  label='Select Chapter Number' 
  onSelect={changeChapterNumber} 
  options={chaptersFromSelectedComic}
/>
<DataList 
  label='Select Chapter Title' 
  onSelect={changeChapter} 
  options={chaptersFromSelectedComic} 
  swap={true}
 />
```

Comment: <option key={option.number} value={swap ? option.title : option.number}>{swap ? option.number : option.title}</option>

Are these supposed to be different or are the ternaries supposed to match? I see that value is the same as the text within the `option`

Also do the above comment.

Comment: @KetanRamteke [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Comment: Curiously, none of the `options` in the docs are closed, so I don't know if this is a typo or actually correct, but it definitely isn't valid in JSX. Tried it in a sandbox. According to [does-react-js-support-html5-datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167565/does-react-js-support-html5-datalist) in react the options tags are closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You've enclosed the list name (`list="items"`) into the component, so all datalist options reference the same initially defined options.

## Solution

Expose out `list` attribute as a prop so each `DataList` component can specify its own set of options.

```
function DataList({
  label,
  list, // <-- add list prop
  onSelect,
  options,
  swap
}) {
  return (
    <DataListContainer>
      <CustomInput
        placeholder={label}
        list={list} // <-- set list attribute for input
        name="item"
        id="item"
        required
        onChange={onSelect}
      ></CustomInput>
      <datalist id={list}> // <-- set id for datalist options
        {options
          ? options.map((option) => (
              <option
                key={option.number}
                value={swap ? option.title : option.number}
              >
                {swap ? option.number : option.title}
              </option>
            ))
          : null}
      </datalist>
    </DataListContainer>
  );
}
```

Pass a `list` prop to each `DataList` component.

```
<DataList list="itemsA" label="List A" options={options} />
<DataList list="itemsB" label="List B" options={options} swap />
```

[image: Edit ternary-operator-fails-when-used-to-set-value-of-datalist-option-in-react-compon]

Comment: Awesome, total oversight on my part but thanks for that, wouldn't have figured it out without you!