# How can I set a data attribute on an element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Silly question but...
I have a div which looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="abc" />
    <div class="abc" />
<div>
```

Can I set the value for the `div.abc` like this `<div class="abc" value={2}></div>`? And then use js to calculate the total by iterate through the child of `div.container`?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, you can. But what are you trying to achieve in higher resolution?

Comment: you need to provide more information to get help.

Comment: You can definitely add attribute with name `value` to a `div` element and go through its children to count the values but there are probably better ways to achieve what you want. If you give us more information maybe we can help you more.

Comment: Im pretty sure `value` is not an official attribute for div elements. I think you should use data attributes instead.

Comment: If it's a React.js question as the tags suggest, why would you want to store values in the DOM instead of state? Doesn't seem too React-y. Maybe start by reading the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Comment: yes @ZsoltMeszaros I know there are state in react but I still want to use the easy way to iterate through value of div instead of iterate through components and then start to take the state out

Comment: According to [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes @MarkBaijens is correct, value is not an official attribute for divs. A data attribute would seem to be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** as [isherwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1264804/isherwood) mentioned in the comments. This answer is just javascript solution and not specific for `reactjs` as I missed that question had `reactjs` tag. See recommended answer [How do I dynamically set HTML5 data- attributes using react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285856/how-do-i-dynamically-set-html5-data-attributes-using-react?noredirect=1&lq=1) for better solution!

You probably looking for [html data attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp)

```html
<div class="container">
    <div data-your-prop="1" />
    <div data-your-prop="1.5" />
    <div data-your-prop="2" />
<div>
```

**e.g. 1**

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.container div[data-your-prop]')

divs.forEach(function (el, index) {
    console.log(el.dataset.yourProp)
})
```

**e.g. 2**

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.container div[data-your-prop]')

let totalInt = 0
let totalFloat = 0
divs.forEach(function (el, index) {
    totalInt += parseInt(el.dataset.yourProp)
    totalFloat += parseFloat(el.dataset.yourProp)
});

console.log(totalInt)
console.log(totalFloat.toFixed(2))

// yields
//
// 4
// "4.50"
```

**note**

(data-) attribute names are attached to `el.dataset` and names defined in dom are normalized to be valid json property.