# Unique identifier for Reactjs children

Tags: html, reactjs, attributes, jsx

I need a unique identifier for children of a Reactjs component. Here is JSX pseudo-code:

```
<ParentComponent>
  <htmlElement1 uniqueIdentifier="htmlElement1" />
  <htmlElement2 uniqueIdentifier="htmlElement2" />
  <ReactElement1 uniqueIdentifier="ReactElement1" />
  <ReactElement2 uniqueIdentifier="ReactElement2" />
</ParentComponent>
```

If I only had React elements I would use `key`, but I also have to handle html elements.

I cannot use `id` because my app is embedded in a page along with other apps and there might be a conflict.

I am currently using `title` but then it doesn't look good as the identifier gets displayed when the user hovers over the element.

Could you recommend a better attribute/prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute, like `data-unique-id="1"`

Comment: Good one! Does it mean I would need two different names, `data-unique-id` for html attributes and `dataUniqueId` for React props?

Comment: If it is not cameCase then you'd have to access it like `this.props['data-unique-id']` inside the component. If camelCase like `dataUniqueId` you can use it like normal props `this.props.dataUniqueId` Detailed answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292918/2333214